# Flet Background image

Tags: python, flet

Is there any method in adding a background image to the page in Flet python. I can find only `.append` `.add` in the docs is it `.overlay` for that.

Thanks in advance.

#### I tried with using .overlay but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to set an image for the page's background which is adding a container to the page as the first control and setting `expand=True` for that:

```py
...
page.padding = 0
page.add(
    Container(
        image_src='<IMAGE_URL>',
        image_fit=ImageFit.COVER,
        expand=True,
        content=Control()
    )
)
...
```

The container's content would be your page body.